# Is there a concept for a "backwards" observer in C#

Tags: c#, events, observer-pattern

I'm trying to get my head around an idea which led me to the observer pattern, but I'm not sure it's the right place to look and I can't find anything on the net (or at least, I'm not asking the right questions ^^).

Following example:

```
// just an enum for a different tool in the ui
private ToolMode _mode;

// updates the UI according to the selected mode
private void UpdateUI(){...};

private void ChangeUIToolToMode1()
{ 
  _mode = ToolMode.Mode1;
  UpdateUI();
}

private void ChangeUIToolToMode2()
{ 
  _mode = ToolMode.Mode2;
  UpdateUI();
}
```

In this example my problem would be that I have to implement the UpadteUI()-call in every ChangeUITool method. What I'm looking for is a way, to add them to a kind of listener which calls the UpdateUI method regardless which of this methods is called, because the application is likely to grow.

Something like this pseudo code:

```
private ToolMode _mode;

private Listener _listener;

private Init()
{
  _listener= new Listener(UpdateUI);
  _listener.invokingEvents.Add(ChangeUIToolToMode1);
  _listener.invokingEvents.Add(ChangeUIToolToMode2);
}
```

If one of the ChangeUITool methods is now called, the listener should call/invoke the UpdateUI method.

Comment: You should encapsulate the current ToolMode in a class (called, say, `CurrentToolMode`) and in that have a property called `CurrentMode` which is the current mode and an `event` called `ModeChanged` which is raised whenever `CurrentToolMode.CurrentMode` is changed. Then anything that needs to do something when `CurrentMode` changes can subscribe to that event.

Comment: You are trying something too complex for the task. Why can't you simply create private property `Mode` and call `UpdateUI` only once in its setter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use full property definition?

```
// property can be private or protected as well, depending on your requirements
public ToolMode Mode
{
    get { return _mode; }
    set
    {
        if (_mode != value)
        {
            _mode = value;
            UpdateUI();
        }
    }
}
```

if `UpdateUI` must be defined outside of class containing `_mode`, there are [`INotyfyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=net-5.0) interface and events:

```
class Foo : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ToolMode _mode;

    public ToolMode Mode
    {
        get { return _mode; }
        set
        {
            if (_mode != value)
            {
                _mode = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Mode)));
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

class Bar
{
    private readonly Foo _foo;

    public Bar()
    {
        _foo = new Foo();
        _foo.PropertyChanged += (sender, args) => UpdateUI();
    }

    private void UpdateUI()
    {
    }

    // ...
}
```

(This is not very good `INPC` implementation, but for demo purpose it's OK)

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to generalise this (and perhaps make it so that you can respond to changes made to the ToolMode from outside the class that is responding to changes) you can just use events in the normal way.

You could encapsulate the current ToolMode in a class, and add to that class an event that will be raised if the ToolMode changes. For example:

```
public sealed class CurrentToolMode
{
    public ToolMode CurrentMode { get; private set; }

    public event EventHandler ModeChanged;

    public void ChangeMode(ToolMode newMode)
    {
        if (newMode == CurrentMode)
            return;

        CurrentMode = newMode;
        ModeChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

And then use it like so:

```
public sealed class Test
{
    public Test(CurrentToolMode mode)
    {
        _mode = mode;
        _mode.ModeChanged += onModeChanged;
    }

    void onModeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateUI();
    }

    void UpdateUI()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("UpdateUI() called; mode was changed to " + _mode.CurrentMode);
    }

    public void SetMode1()
    {
        _mode.ChangeMode(ToolMode.Mode1);
    }

    public void SetMode2()
    {
        _mode.ChangeMode(ToolMode.Mode2);
    }

    readonly CurrentToolMode _mode;
}
```

In the example above, `CurrentToolMode` is passed in to the constructor, so that it could be modified from other classes. Alternatively, you could create it in the constructor so that nothing else can change it - it depends on your usage pattern.

Here's a compilable console app demonstrating its use:

```
using System;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Test test = new Test(new CurrentToolMode());
            test.SetMode1();
            test.SetMode2();
        }
    }

    public sealed class Test
    {
        public Test(CurrentToolMode mode)
        {
            _mode = mode;
            _mode.ModeChanged += onModeChanged;
        }

        void onModeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateUI();
        }

        void UpdateUI()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("UpdateUI() called; mode was changed to " + _mode.CurrentMode);
        }

        public void SetMode1()
        {
            _mode.ChangeMode(ToolMode.Mode1);
        }

        public void SetMode2()
        {
            _mode.ChangeMode(ToolMode.Mode2);
        }

        readonly CurrentToolMode _mode;
    }

    public enum ToolMode
    {
        None,
        Mode1,
        Mode2
    }

    public sealed class CurrentToolMode
    {
        public ToolMode CurrentMode { get; private set; }

        public event EventHandler ModeChanged;

        public void ChangeMode(ToolMode newMode)
        {
            if (newMode == CurrentMode)
                return;

            CurrentMode = newMode;
            ModeChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

The output of that code is:

```
UpdateUI() called; mode was changed to Mode1
UpdateUI() called; mode was changed to Mode2
```

I should stress that this kind of solution is completely overkill if you are only going to use it in a limited number of methods in one class, but it demonstrates a generic approach to responding to settings changes in a decoupled way. This approach allows any number of classes to respond to a settings change.

Here's a compilable example showing the mode being changed from outside the class responding to the mode changes:

```
using System;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            CurrentToolMode mode = new CurrentToolMode();
            Test test = new Test(mode);
            mode.ChangeMode(ToolMode.Mode1);
            mode.ChangeMode(ToolMode.Mode2);
        }
    }

    public sealed class Test
    {
        public Test(CurrentToolMode mode)
        {
            _mode = mode;
            _mode.ModeChanged += onModeChanged;
        }

        void onModeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateUI();
        }

        void UpdateUI()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("UpdateUI() called; mode was changed to " + _mode.CurrentMode);
        }

        readonly CurrentToolMode _mode;
    }

    public enum ToolMode
    {
        None,
        Mode1,
        Mode2
    }

    public sealed class CurrentToolMode
    {
        public ToolMode CurrentMode { get; private set; }

        public event EventHandler ModeChanged;

        public void ChangeMode(ToolMode newMode)
        {
            if (newMode == CurrentMode)
                return;

            CurrentMode = newMode;
            ModeChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```